# Water is not coming from/out of the tap

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If we turn on the tap and water doesn't flow out of it,what will be used:

> Water is not coming **from** the tap .
>
> Water is not coming **out of** the tap.
>
> There is no water **in** the tap..

What should be used: "out of/from"? Or the third sentence

---

### In a different context

An agency provides water to people in a region through pipes. So one day there's no water( i.e. water is not coming out of that tap that is connected to that agency's pipe) so, what will be used:

> Water is not **coming** today.

Does it sound natural? Or will it be: **There's no water today in the tap.**

### **So what will be used in both the contexts?**

Answer (score 1):

Simpler is better:

> There is no tap water (today).

or:

> Tap water will not be available on May 4th.